# Loose light up apple logo on unibody macbook case

Tags: macbook-pro

The light-up Apple logo inset into on the back of my 13" Unibody MacBook ([this thing](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3353/3181239953_e16734e462.jpg)) has come loose and is recessed into the lid. Is there a way to get inside the lid to reattach that piece? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please note that just about anything that you do to open up the case in order to fix this will void your warranty.

Comment: @MarkSzymanski that's not completely true. upgrading the hdd / memory yourself won't void warranty. if you do it properly. so as long as you don't break anything it's all good. ( I did ask this at a apple repair shop )

Comment: @FLY, in this case it is true though.  Hard drives and RAM can be upgraded by simply removing the bottom case, this is why they are classified as "User Serviceable" components.  The display assembly involves several steps beyond that to remove, and then many more much riskier steps to disassemble.  I say riskier as the display assembly was for a long time only available as one complete component.  If the lid cracked, the LCD cracked, the bezel cracked, etc you had to replace the entire assembly.  Only recently (6+ months?) has Apple made other components of the display available to providers.

Answer (score 1):

iFixit has directions on opening the lid: [Installing Front Display Bezel](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-MacBook-Unibody-Model-A1342-Front-Display-Bezel/2985/1).
It requires their $3 [Spudger](http://www.ifixit.com/Tools/Spudger/IF145-002?utm_source=ifixit_guide&utm_medium=guide_intro&utm_content=required_items&utm_term=macbook_unibody_model_a1342) tool.